# "Any sort of situation" or "any sort of situations"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Once any sort of unique name(s) comes up, I'm lost.
>
> I lose it when any sort of strange situation(s) comes up.

Since "situation" and "name" here are count nouns, should they be in the plural? The singular strikes me as wrong in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singular sounds wrong because you’re referring to any number of names or situations, but it is actually correct because the technical referent “sort” is singular.

Comment: Welcome, Josh. I notice you're a newcomer and this is three out of three answers I think you got pretty much spot on. :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. So should I use singular nouns or plural nouns after "sort of"?

Comment: Singular is correct